# regex for including 'Demo' term but not 'Test Demo'

Tags: regex, scala

I have a column as col1 and col2:

```
col1             col2          is_demo     is_test_demo
Demo             test demo     true        true
test Demo        test          true        true  
project Demo     demo          true        false
app demo         test          true        false
```

I have created 2 column with 2 regex which searches in both col1 or col2- is_demo(with *(?)Demo* term) and is_test_demo(with *(?i)test demo* term)

required result:

```
col1             col2
Demo             test demo   
project Demo     demo
app demo         test
```

basically i want to **remove only those data where only test demo is there**
Can anyone suggest if where I am wrong here and how can i achieve the result

The code tried:
added 2 regex columns -

is_demo -

```
col1.like("(?i)demo") or col2.like("(?i)demo")
```

is_test_demo -

```
col1.like("(?i)test demo") or col2.like("(?i)test demo")
```

and I was trying if is_demo and not(is_test_demo)
but its not working.

*Can anyone please help me to get the regex for including*
    wherever its demo but and not(test demo)

Comment: can you please give out the code that you tried

Comment: updated the question. thanks

Comment: Try rlike instead:  `col1.rlike("(?i)test demo") or col2.rlike("(?i)test demo")`

Comment: actually i needa regex for incluing *demo* but exclude if its test demo..

Comment: @drlol Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/St80h6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regex I think you could use [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike). To match demo but not if the string contains test_demo you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is on the right is not test demo between word boundaries to prevent being part of a larger word:

```
(?i)^(?!.*Test Demo).*\bdemo\b.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/St80h6/1)